# How to calculate TilesOrigin for WebGeoCache in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geowebcache

I'm using OpenLayers 5.2 to display tiles from Geoserver 2.14 with GeoWebCache.
For the GeoWebCache to work it is required to define `tiled=true` and `tilesorigin` parameters in the WMS requests.

How to I get the `tilesorigin` value in OpenLayers?

Comment: You can use any origin which suits your application, but you must set the same value for your WMS and the OpenLayers tile grid https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_tilegrid_TileGrid-TileGrid.html

Comment: What is the purpose of this tilesorigin parameter in general? Should I get it from the tilegrid global extent or from the current view extent or from the curent grid orgin value? Another thing I noticed is that according to Geoserver's documentation it should be bottom-left corder of the extent but in OpenLayers it is top-left corder by default.

Comment: Set the bottom left of the maximum extent you want your application to use in both the OpenLayers tilegGrid and the WMS parameters   The default OpenLayers top left origin is intended for XYZ layers, it's not suitable for WMS.

Comment: I have neither projection nor tilegrid defined for the TileWMS source. Neither there is extent nor project defined for the map view. Everything is based on default values. How do I get the default tilegrid extent then? Will `map.getView().getProjection().getWorldExtent()` or `.getExtent()` do?

Comment: Use the maximum extent supported by your WMS, unless you want to restrict your application to a smaller extent.  If your view has no projection specified it will default to EPSG:3857, is that the same as your WMS is serving?

Comment: My data is in EPSG:4326 served by Geoserver and the OpenLayers app makes wms requests with the default EPSG:3857. It works correctly in the normal tile mode (when tiled=true is not defined in the wms request parameters) but I want to switch to meta-tiling mode which requires the `tilesorigin` parameter. When you say "the maximum extent supported by your WMS" do you mean the extent of my data? I can find it in the Geoserver admin panel but it is in EPSG:4326, so I guess it needs to be matched with the OpenLayers EPSG:3857 somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is being requested in EPSG:3857 you could simply set the OpenLayers WMS parameters

```
tiled: true,
tilesorigin: ol.extent.getBottomLeft(ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent()).toString(),
```

The standard XYZ (OpenLayers default) tilegrid for EPSG:3857 is square and tiles originate at each corner, so although OpenLayers uses top left internally the default grid would still work.  But for other projections with different extents it probably wouldn't.

If your data isn't global the easiest way to restrict the extent without having to set up a custom tilegrid is to set the extent option in the `ol.layer.Tile` constructor (you can use `ol.prog.transformExtent` to transform a Lon/Lat bbox)

Comment: Thanks, Mike. That's exaclty what I was trying to find out. Since my map is in the default EPSG:3857 projection I've managed to get the same result with `ol.extent.getBottomLeft(map.getView().getProjection().getExtent()).toString()` call.